# Can the orientation of Hard Drives cause them to run slow?

Tags: hard-drive, speed, orientation

I've got a Dell PowerEdge server with 6 2TB drives in a RAID6 that I use to run several VM's at home. I recently moved it from a temporary location to a more permanent location. While the new location is over all much better, it does leave the machine sitting at an angle (about 10 degrees off of flat).

Since I've moved the machine, I've noticed that the HD access times are much slower. I don't have raw stats from before the move, but reading a large file runs at only 1-3 MB/s. By comparison, a nearly identical disk running alone in another computer can read at well more than 100 MB/s.

Would a 10-15 degree tilt in the HD's cause this? Would fixing the orientation fix it? Or should I assume that the hard drives might be failing?

Answer (score 4):

No, the orientation of a modern hard drive is not relevant to it's performance or life span, any number of articles are available online to backup that statement. Although it is recommended (mostly by conventional wisdom, not fact) that they should be formatted when parallel or perpendicular to the ground.

There is something else going on that is causing the issue. Since you moved the computer, it is possible that the HDDs were damaged, but it is more likely that a cable or RAID controller is not seated correctly.

Further investigation is warranted to find the cause of the issue, but the answer to your question is clear... the orientation of the drives is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

i think it's much more likely to be failing. some computer chassis actually have mounts for hard drives to be vertical, which i am using at present. i'd mount as read-only, or unmount entirely if you can, and run:

```
 smartctl -t long /dev/sd?
 smartctl -l selftest
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S.M.A.R.T.

of course it could be something else entirely ?

Comment: Can you double check your link (it doesn't contain any content)?  Were you looking for something like this: http://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl  ?

Comment: ah that's because the punctuation mark at the very end of the link was not automatically registering as part of the link, which i've fixed now. but yeah it's kinda like the man page but more sparsely/clearly laid out than a man page and with more examples.